# Execution of a single rule for a group in Drools

Tags: java, drools, expert-system

I am working on an expert system based on legislation, I have many rules like these:

Rule 1:
If the seizure has an amount greater than 3000, seize the amount, justification law 100

Rule 2: If the seizure is of a family type, seize the amount, justification law 200

The problem is that the action "Seize" can only be applied once, but I need to save the history of the rules that are met, I present an example below

```
rule "law 100"

when 
  $seizure: Seizure(amount>3000)
then
  $seizure.getRules().add("Justification: law 100 of the civil that says bla bla");
  $seizure.applyPunishment();

rule "law 200"

when 
  $seizure: Seizure(type == TYPES.Family)
then
  $seizure.getRules().add("Justification: law 200 of the family code that says bla bla");
  $seizure.applyPunishment();
```

As I showed above, I need the "then" part that save the description rule "$seizure.getRules().add("Justification: law  of the civil code");". and I also need that if the "$seizure.applyPunishment();" was already applied in rule 1, it will not be reapplied in the rule 2.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. Change `applyPunishment` to be idempotent.

   You don't show the code for `applyPunishment`, but it could look like

   ```
   private boolean alreadySeized = false;

   public void applyPunishment() {
       if (alreadySeized) {
           return;
       }

       alreadySeized = true;
   ```

   You could also base this on some other variable that already exists.  E.g. `if (seizedAmount > 0) return;`.  But it's hard to say how that might work without the code.
2. You could change `applyPunishment` to something like `markForPunishment`, which could look like

   ```
   private boolean markedForPunishment;

   public void markForPunishment() {
       markedForPunishment = true;
   }
   ```

   Then add a rule like

   ```
   rule "Punish"

   when
     $seizure: Seizure(markedForPunishment  == true)
   then
     $seizure.applyPunishment();
   ```

   With an appropriate getter.

   Your other rules would call `markForPunishment` rather than `applyPunishment`.
3. You could use a [ruleflow](https://github.com/nheron/droolsonboarding/blob/master/gettingStarted/lesson_4__ruleflow.md) to separate the justifications from the punishment.
4. You could [set a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104493/6660678) in your then clause that you use in your rules.

There are probably other options.  The big decision to make is whether you want an MVEL solution or a Java solution.  Several of the options will require changing both.